# Why does subform not display all results

Tags: sql, ms-access, ms-access-2010

I have an Access Form with various dropdowns. The form contains a report in a subform. The report is based on the following SQL statement which references the dropdowns on the main form:

```
SELECT imp_rule_CURRENT.target
    ,imp_rule_CURRENT.Phase
    ,imp_phase.SortOrder
    ,imp_rule_CURRENT.Solicitation
    ,imp_rule_CURRENT.Qualification
    ,imp_rule_CURRENT.Activity
    ,imp_rule_CURRENT.ClientLocation
    ,imp_rule_CURRENT.ProviderLocation
    ,imp_rule_CURRENT.Answer
    ,imp_rule_CURRENT.Comment
    ,imp_ActivityList_Test_PB_MetaversionC2.HeadingText
    ,imp_answer.full_name
    ,imp_answer.icon2
    ,imp_phase.Chapter
    ,tbl_Country.short_name
    ,IIf([Forms]![frm_ClientModel]![ckbYesOnly], InStr([Answer], "is_yes") > 0, - 1) AS Is_Yes
FROM imp_phase
INNER JOIN (
    imp_answer INNER JOIN (
        tbl_Country INNER JOIN (
            imp_ActivityList_Test_PB_MetaversionC2 INNER JOIN imp_rule_CURRENT 
                ON imp_ActivityList_Test_PB_MetaversionC2.SignatureTagSet = imp_rule_CURRENT.Activity
            ) ON tbl_Country.ISO_Country = imp_rule_CURRENT.target
        ) ON imp_answer.code_name = imp_rule_CURRENT.Answer
    ) ON imp_phase.code_name = imp_rule_CURRENT.Phase
WHERE (
        ((imp_rule_CURRENT.target) = [Forms]![frm_ClientModel]![cmbCountry])
        AND ((imp_rule_CURRENT.Phase) 
            LIKE IIf([Forms]![frm_ClientModel]![cmbPhase] = "ALL", "*", [Forms]![frm_ClientModel]![cmbPhase]))
        AND ((imp_rule_CURRENT.Solicitation) = [Forms]![frm_ClientModel]![txt_Initiative])
        AND ((imp_rule_CURRENT.Qualification) = [Forms]![frm_ClientModel]![txt_Qualification])
        AND ((imp_rule_CURRENT.ClientLocation) = [Forms]![frm_ClientModel]![txt_MeetingLocation_Client])
        AND ((imp_rule_CURRENT.ProviderLocation) = [Forms]![frm_ClientModel]![txt_MeetingLocation_Bank])
        AND ((imp_rule_CURRENT.Answer) <> "is_not_applicable")
        AND ((IIf([Forms]![frm_ClientModel]![ckbYesOnly], InStr([Answer], "is_yes") > 0, - 1)) = True)
        )
ORDER BY imp_phase.SortOrder;
```

When I have form open and the following part of the SQL statement evaluates to True `Like IIf([Forms]![frm_ClientModel]![cmbPhase]="ALL","*",[Forms]![frm_ClientModel]![cmbPhase]))` the query, when opened manually, shows all results as I would expect. Yet the subform which is based on this query shows no results.

**Question:** Why does the subform not show any results and how can I get the subform to show them?

**Update 2:**
I have tested and found out that if I view the report upon which the subform is based, then the correct results show. As noted in a comment below, the subform report works as intended when I selected anything other than "ALL". Results are shown for every other item seleted in the subform, just not when I select the option "ALL". Those results are not shown in the subquery, yet oddly they do show if I open the report manualy. So perhaps the problem is somehow linked to the subform?

Comment: Well formatted SQL makes everything so much easier, both to read and to write.

Comment: Wo you mean here on SO or that my SQL is not well formatted per se? If on here, how can I format it better? I find it annoying myself.

Comment: @rohrl77: You can do SQL formatting in notepad++ with a third party plugin. Here is the link :- https://github.com/sqlparser/isf_notepad

Comment: @GauravS Thank! I can't install anything at work, but I will give it a go on my home PC. Looks very useful!

Comment: Simply do line breaks and single steps.

Comment: I think I got it! Take a look. Thank you!

Comment: Do you have code in combobox AfterUpdate event to requery the subreport? This all works for me. Also did a test of instead of a saved query object, I used SQL statement in report RecordSource and excluded the form prefix from the parameter, just [cmbPhase]. The filter works without VBA code. In both, the IIf() expression was the only filter criteria, nothing as complex as you have.

Comment: @June7 I do not have any VBA events triggered by the report. Thanks for looking in to it! I'll post updates as I find out new behavior.

Comment: Do you have any linked fields between your main form and the subform?

Comment: @GauravS I use "Poor Man's T-Sql Formatter" in NP++ and it's great but the only hangup is in Access, like this question, sometimes there are `!` which are formatted to have spaces surrounding them, ` ! `, which obviously breaks an Access query. Does the one you use do  a better job?

Comment: @SunKnight0 I do not have any linked fields between the subform and the main form. The only connection is through the controls refrenced in the query.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I still don't understand why this is the case, but the answer to my problem was that **the query of the mainform had to be adjusted to include the new statement.** despite the subform NOT being linked to the main form.

As noted in my update, when I opened the query manually it worked fine. When I opened the report that was based on the query it worked fine. Only when I tried to open the report through the subform did it not show the expected result.

This finally led me to the insight that perhaps, under certain circumstances, the record set that was being shown was restricted somehow.

The main form that I had set up was itself based on a query. I had not updated that query to contain the new `Like IIf([Forms]![frm_ClientModel]![cmbPhase]="ALL","*",[Forms]![frm_ClientModel]![cmbPhase]))` command. Despite my subform NOT being linked to the main one, it restricted the recordset available to display.

Comment: I would like to say "Thank you" to all that read my problem and tried to provide a solution!

Answer (score 0):

Are you re-querying the subreport after the update?
Your code should include something along these lines, where `rvSubReportView` is the sub-report object:

```
rvSubReportView.Report.Requery
```

This would be in the `AfterUpdate()` function for the main form's `ComboBox` control.

Comment: I do a requery on the full form. The requery is triggered after any control element is changed. I should note that the query works in the subform when I select anything other than "ALL". Results are displayed for any other selection.